# Invoke a C# method from inside a SQL trigger

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I am into a Winforms application using C# and Visual Studio 2010 along with SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2.

My application checks the previous values in the database and if the current value being inserted falls under a certain range, I need to execute a method written in C# i.e. the host language. The method actually sends E-mails to the e-mail addresses stored in the database.

Now the checking part can be easily done using a trigger but the latter is troublesome for me.

Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to handle this.

1. You could log an entry to a database that a C# service watches, and when an entry is added, it sends e-mails.  This could be some sort of a Windows Service that runs on a Timer every 1 minute checking for updates.
2. You can use the [SQL-CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to integrate C# code with SQL code.  This requires opening a few security points and embedding the binary files from your project into SQL Server.  This is a less preferred method for security reasons, but it can do the job.

Comment: Will method 1. work if my Win-Forms application is shut-down? Say n records are added to the database but when they were trying to be    e-mailed, the user shuts down the application. 
If it does work, how do we do it?

Comment: I think what mellamokb proposes with (1) is a second program ( a windows service that starts with the windows operating system on the database server ) that monitors the table for new entries and then does the work. This is a usual pattern and I know several places where it is used. There is no need to have the main application running.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into [Database Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887.aspx). This integrates email sending functionality within SQL Server.

Otherwise, I'd strongly suggest not trying to do this directly within the trigger - sending an email could be a time consuming process, and you wouldn't want to delay the completion of the transaction if the email functionality isn't currently working.